# At what point does both right hand and left hand limits exist, but the limit does not exist? Give your reason.

Tags: functions

Question 1

Consider the function defined by
$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x^2 - 1, & \text{if $x \leq 0$}\\
x - 2, & \text{if $0 < x < 1$}\\
c, & \text{if $x = 1$}\\
-x, & \text{if $x > 1$}
\end{cases}
$$

(a) At what point does both right hand and left hand limits exist, but the limit does not exist? Give your reason.
(4 marks)

(b) Find the value of $c$ for which $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=1$.  Give your reason.
(6 marks)

Current ANSWER:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yo1pS.jpg)
not sure if answer a is correct.
not sure about the method to solve question b

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question on this site, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please [edit] the question to tell us what you know, show what you have attempted, and explain where you are stuck so that you receive answers that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Also, I do not understand how the title relates to the question.  Please revise your title.

Comment: Your working for part (a) seems very clear. What in particular is your reason for doubt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

b) for continuity at $x=1$ at first we have to do $\lim_{x\to 1-}$ $f(x)$ = $\lim_{x\to 1+}$ $f(x)$ = $\lim_{x\to 1}$ $f(x)$ .

Here ,
 $\lim_{x\to 1-}$ $f(x)$  = $\lim_{x\to 1+}$ $f(x)$ $= -1$

So, for continuity $c$ must be $-1$.